# covariance in multiple linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, regression-coefficients

This is a general question Im trying to understand. Say for example you have two timeseries, ts1 and ts2, and the correlation between ts1 and ts2 is 0.5 (corr(ts1,ts2) = 0.5). If the MLR model is of the form: f = u0 + u1$*$ts1 + u2$*$ts2, then what can we say about the relationship between the coefficients u1 and u2? Do they share the same relationship as the input timeseries or are they computed to be more "orthogonal" and account for the covariance between the independent vars?